# At most finite elements of the sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^+}$ is nonzero under certain conditions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, soft-question, operator-theory, matrix-equations

Let $\{x_{n}: n\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}\}$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that $$\sum\limits_{p\in \mathbb{Z}_{+}}\vert x_{p} \vert^2=1$$ and

$$\sum\limits_{p\in \mathbb{Z}_{+} }x_{p} \overline{x_{p+r}}=0~~ \text{for all}~~ r\geq 1.$$
Does it imply at most finitely many $x_{p}$ can be non zero. Can you please provide  ideas how to solve this?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't have an answer, but if only finitely many $x_p$ are nonzero, then only one is nonzero. Because if $x_{p_1},\ldots,x_{p_m}$ are nonzero, then $$\sum_k x_k\overline{x_{k+(p_m-p_1)}}=x_{p_1}\overline{x_{p_m}}\ne0.$$

Comment: Dear Martin, thanks for sharing your thoughts.  I also don't have any idea how to tackle this question.

Answer (score 4):

There is a counterexample to your question.

Set $x_{1}=1$.

For $n \geq 2$ set $x_{n} = q^{n-2}$ where $q = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Note that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_{j}|^2 = 1+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}q^{2k} = 1+\frac{1}{1-q^2}= \frac{\sqrt{5}+3}{2} = 1+\phi$

Thus $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\phi}}x_{j})_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is a normalized sequence.

We claim that $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\phi}}x_{j})_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is a $\textbf{counterexample}$. We can ignore the normalization factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\phi}}$ for the computation below.

For $r \geq  1,$ $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}x_{j}\overline{x_{j+r}}$ is

$$(q^{r-1})+\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}q^{j-2}q^{r+j-2}$$

$$ =  q^{r-1} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}q^{r+2k}$$

$$ = q^{r-1}+q^{r}\frac{1}{1-q^{2}}$$

$$ = q^{r-1}(\frac{1-q^2+q}{1-q^2})$$

Note $1-q^2+q = 0$ by wolfram alpha, thus the above quantity is $0$.

$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\phi}}x_{j})_{j=1}^{\infty}$ is a $\textbf{counterexample}$ to your question.

Comment: Using "by wolfram alpha" as an argument here seems strange

Comment: Yeah...I just wanted to make sure